# Can I run nodetool repair concurrently?

Tags: scylla

Is it possible (a good idea) to run `nodetool repair -st $FROM -et $TO` on multiple Scylla nodes concurrently while making sure that token ranges do not overlap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Scylla manager takes this tactic too.